# Wrap array into custom string based on the array

Tags: php, arrays, string

So I have a list that looks like the following:

```
 $mylist = array('100003028593816', '1784394111', '100008137385157', '100000462582000','100001633550680', '100000757743079');
```

(This list can vary based on different inputs, etc. This is just an example)

I want to create a STRING from that array that looks like the following.

```
$string = '{"100003028593816":1,"1784394111":1,"100008137385157":1,"100000462582000":1,"100001633550680":1,"100000757743079":1}'
```

(NOTE: See how they are the same values as above, they're just wrapped up differently. That's how they need to be posted. So I pretty much want to take the values from the array and wrap them as {"value1":1,"value2":1} etc.

In python I used

```
 mystring= '{' + ','.join(map(lambda x: '"' + x + '":1', mylist)) + '}'
```

Which did the trick. I'm just not sure what the proficent way to do it in PHP is.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `array_fill_keys`, and encode the array with `json_encode`:

```
echo json_encode(array_fill_keys($mylist, 1));
```

Output:

```
{"100003028593816":1,"1784394111":1,"100008137385157":1,"100000462582000":1,"100001633550680":1,"100000757743079":1}
```

Comment: I have never used `array_fill_keys()` and it didn't even occur to me.

Comment: Don't tell me about it, I just found it by chance.